# paypal link for subscription with start date

Tags: html, paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I found link for making buy now payments using PayPal. For example, the following link is used for payment for Buy Now buttons:

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=example@yourwebsite.com&cmd=_xclick&currency_code=USD&amount=99&item_name=productname
```

where it uses some variables like business(for receiver's email), `amount`, `item_name`,etc..,

I am looking for a link just like the above for subscriptions with start date, i.e, a valid variable for specifying the subscription to start. I Googled it and I found the variable `subscr_date` can be used for specifying the start date. but I don't know how to make a proper working link for subscription with start date.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the two. PayPal does provide a query string button for Buy Now but I don't recall ever seeing one for subscriptions. Instead, those buttons typically contain a form with all of your options.

PayPal does have a simpler solution now. Their [Javascript Buttons](http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/) library appears to greatly simplify this process. I think this might do what you want it to.

```
<script src="paypal-button.min.js?merchant=YOUR_MERCHANT_ID"
    data-button="subscribe"
    data-name="My product"
    data-amount="1.00"
    data-recurrence="1"
    data-period="M"
    async
></script>
```

If that still won't work, you will need to use the [Payments Standard HTML](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/subscribe_buttons/), which also supports recurring payments

Comment: but i saw this link working but i just need to know how to add the start date to it      `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=example@gmail.com&cmd=_xclick-subscriptions&currency_code=USD&a3=25&p3=12&t3=M&item_name=Doanete%20To%20Our%20Service&txn_type=subscr_signup&subscr_date=1-1-2015`

Comment: is it possible to add start date to the code you've sent?

Comment: I would read the documentation and see. The list of options is too long to print here.

Comment: can you send the link here?

Comment: Machavity correctly refers to the docs. PayPal Standard HTML Payments (or whatever it is called these days) does function with simple GET URLs (as opposed to the POST buttons), with all the same parameters. You can take any PayPal Standard (non-js) button and convert to a GET URL format, or build a similar URL using the docs. But I don't know if this is officially supported functionality so I would recommend against making a real/permanant/production integration this way. Building your own buttons is supported, but it is safest to stick to POST rather than GET.